# Email id of form submitter in Google chat bot

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

With below code I am  generating a google chatbot response when a user fills the form. The user fills the forms, on sibmit, a chatbot response is generated in the Google chat app.
I am able to get all the fields from the form, that are a output in the chat, but i wanted to add email id of the user as well. I know the form records the email id automatically as a field 'Email id" but I am unable to get it in the chat bot notification as a separate field - "email-xx@xx.com"

Any help would be appreciated. Attaching code below -

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  
  var formResponse = e.response
  
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
 
  var rname="",ecr="",rgld="",red="""
  var responsearray=[],questionarray=["Requestor Name","Category of Change Request:","Requested Go Live Date","Requested End Date (Max 7 days from today)"];
  for (var i=0; i<itemResponses.length; i++) {
    switch (itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle()) {
      case "Requestor Name":
        rname = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
        break;
      case "Category of Change Request:":
        ecr = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
        break;
      case "Requested Go Live Date":
        rgld = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
        break;
      case "Requested End Date (Max 7 days from today)":
        red = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
        break;

  }
  responsearray.push(rname)
  responsearray.push(ecr)
  responsearray.push(rgld)
  responsearray.push(red)

  
  var message = "A new request has been raised by " ,questionanswer=""; 
  responsearray.forEach((response,index)=>{
    if(response!=""){
      
      if(questionanswer==""){
        questionanswer = questionarray[index]+"-"+response

      }
      else{
        questionanswer = questionanswer +"\n"+ questionarray[index]+"-"+response

      }
      

    }
  })

  if(questionanswer!="" && ecr=="Emergency Change Request (DO NOT USE - UNDER CONSTRUCTION)"){
    message = message +" "+ questionanswer
    webhook(message);

  }

  

}

function webhook(message) {

  
  const url = "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAACZKTqrc/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=Zcf9bZSpsrrxX5JxpHaV57fDn18Iq8tJhtmy14uxVtc%3D"; //replace here your registered webhook url 
  const options = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "text": message
    })
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  //Logger.log(response);
}
```

Hi All,

With below code I am  generating a google chatbot response when a user fills the form. The user fills the forms, on sibmit, a chatbot response is generated in the Google chat app.
I am able to get all the fields from the form, that are a output in the chat, but i wanted to add email id of the user as well. I know the form records the email id automatically as a field 'Email id" but I am unable to get it in the chat bot notification as a separate field - "email-xx@xx.com"

Any help would be appreciated. Attaching code below

Comment: `red="""`  is a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FormResponse object will include the email address of the of the person who submitted a response, you'll just need to make sure that the setting "Collect email addresses" is turned on here:

[image: Setting]

Then, use `FormResponse.getRespondentEmail();` to get the email address. This is how it would work using your code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var formResponse = e.response
  var emailAddress = formResponse.getRespondentEmail(); // <-- Capture email address
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var rname = "", ecr = "", rgld = "", red = ""; 

...

if (questionanswer != "" && ecr == "Emergency Change Request (DO NOT USE - UNDER CONSTRUCTION)") {
    //Append the email address to end the message:
    questionanswer = questionanswer + "\nEmail address -" + emailAddress; 

    message = message + " " + questionanswer
    webhook(message);

  }

}
```

---

#### Docs:

- [FormResponse methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#methods)